# Eclipse SVN connection timeout

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-kepler

I'm using Eclipse Kepler and connect to SVN via VPN. Sometimes VPN connection drops and when I try do do commit without connection I have to wait for 10 minutes until timeout.

The SVN console shows:

```
commit -m "...comment..." -N ...file_list...
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Connection timed out
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://192.168.9.2:81/svn/...'
svn: Connection timed out
```

Why it takes 10 minutes to get timeout? How can I change it?

---

EDIT:

Maybe it is related to network routing problem. With VPN is disconnected `ping 192.168.9.2` gets timeout instead of unreachable host.

Comment: Would suggest looking for svn settings in the settings dialog. I don't know if there are any for this but worth a shot.

Comment: Heh, that would be too easy. No such settings in Kepler.

Comment: Agreed.  is that the subclipse plugin your using?

Comment: you might try info from here.  if that helps let me know and I will make it an answer:  http://www.wandisco.com/svnforum/forum/opensource-subversion-forums/general-setup-and-troubleshooting/tortoisesvn-community-support/9448-howto-change-timeout-delay-time

Comment: I've just added `http-timeout = 5` to the `servers` file and it works! Thank you! I will be glad to accept your answer.

Comment: Great, I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

(If you're connecting to your SVN using http protocol) Try setting the `http-timeout` property in (`[global]` or relevant server-group section of the) `servers` file in your subversion *home* (at `%APPDATA%\Subversion\servers` on Windows) to a low enough value (in seconds - say like 30), so that subversion realizes the connection is kaput sooner, and causes an error message pop-up!

(By default, bottom of) The file should looks something like this:

```
[global]
http-timeout = 30
```

History:

I also had issues with work VPN every now and then, and google took me to this old question. @lhasadad commented that he posted an answer but I couldn't see one (I don't know if this method did not work for him, or why the post was deleted, but I could confirm that it still works! (that is, it makes the handling of connection issue better)). Unfortunately that forum link is also giving 404 atm. So I dived into wayback machine and found [a copy from April 2016](https://web.archive.org/web/20160422161135if_/https://www.wandisco.com/svnforum/forum/opensource-subversion-forums/general-setup-and-troubleshooting/tortoisesvn-community-support/9448-howto-change-timeout-delay-time)! Credits go to "stefan", a moderator of that forum. He also mentions (if you have Tortoise), this servers file can be opened by "Settings\Network[Edit]" in that GUI.